# How often has a team beaten another team from the same league four times in a season?

Tags: football, trivia, english-premier-league

Manchester United have beaten Nottingham Forest four times in the 2022/2023 season. Twice in the League Cup Semifinal and twice in the league.

I was wondering how often something like this has happened? You can add Europe's top 5 league's but how many times has a team beaten another team from the same league four times in a season? I'm wondering if that is as rare an event, as what I think it is?

Comment: I've just looked at the same exact scenario (2 wins in EPL and 2 wins in League Cup semifinal) and found at least two examples in recent years: [Chelsea - Tottenham 21-22](https://www.11v11.com/teams/chelsea/tab/opposingTeams/opposition/Tottenham%20Hotspur/) and [Manchester City - West Ham United 13-14](https://www.11v11.com/teams/manchester-city/tab/opposingTeams/opposition/West%20Ham%20United/). I believe we can find more cases like this if we take into account FA Cup, UEFA tournaments and friendlies, but I'm not sure how often something like this happens

Comment: Champions League can also add to such instances. This season (2022-23) [Inter Milan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022%E2%80%9323_Inter_Milan_season) and [A.C. Milan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022%E2%80%9323_A.C._Milan_season) faced each other five times (twice in Serie A, twice in the Champions League and once in Supercoppa Italiana), Inter won four of those matches. Wikipedia: [Milan Derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derby_della_Madonnina)

Comment: Since you only ask for the top 5 leagues, I'll add it as a comment: There are leagues which different formats where it's more common that teams play each other 4 times in the national competition. E.g: Belgium, in the 2021-22 season Anderlecht lost 4 times to Union SG. https://www.transfermarkt.be/rsc-anderlecht/bilanz/verein/58/plus/0?saison_id=2021&land_id=19&wettbewerb_id=&clubs_in_comp_id=&heim_gast=&day=&punkte=&group=1&datum_von=01.05.2021&datum_bis=31.05.2022